# Object-fit: cover is not clipping img inside 3:4 (75% padding) container inside bootstrap grid

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a 3:4 box that takes all sorts of images. This box is in a bootstrap grid. object-fit:cover is applied to img but seems to have absolutely no effect (no object-fit value seems to be applying at all). The images are squashing instead of clipping. In Firefox and Safari (have not tried Chrome).

Is there a way to make 3:4 box that resizes with bootstrap take object-fit: cover?

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
}

.box img {
    position: absolute;

    padding:3px;
    margin: 0; 

    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;

    object-fit: cover !Important; 
    object-position: 50% 50%;
}

<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box">
                   <img src="anysize.jpg">
                </div>          
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What do you recommend?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image inside of the box so that the image height and width ratio should be 3:4.

You have to do something like this:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.image_box{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 75%;
}
.image_box img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="image_box">
                    <img src="https://www.sammobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/keyguard_default_wallpaper_silver.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="image_box">
                    <img src="https://www.sammobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/keyguard_default_wallpaper_silver.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="image_box">
                    <img src="https://www.sammobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/keyguard_default_wallpaper_silver.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you indicate how what you have is different from what I have? Seems identical to me?

Comment: Can you confirm this works for you? In Firefox and Safari the object fit: cover is not applying. Thx!